# How to create a relationship between two nodes with common properties?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I think I am asking this question right.
The data in my node looks like this:

```
Car      Speed
---      -----
Farrari  80
Corvette 92
Farrari  135
Corvette 129
Porche   78
Porche   150
```

I want to create a relationship called HIGH_SPEED between the two same cars with the highest speed and the lowest speed of the car. So essentially relationship should look like this:

```
                  ___________                        ___________
                 /           \                      /           \
                /             \    High Speed      /             \
               |  Car: Porche  |_________________\|  Car: Porche  |  
               |  Speed: 78    |                 /|  Speed: 150   |
                \             /                    \             /
                 \___________/                      \___________/
```

This is what I have got so far. This creates an empty relationship.

```
MATCH (c_max:CARS), (c_min:CARS)
with c_max.name as max_name, max(c_max.speed) as max_speed
   , c_min.name as min_name, min(c_min.speed) as min_speed
WHERE c_max.name = c_min.name
FOREACH (x IN max_name |
  FOREACH (y IN min_name |
    CREATE (x)-[:HIGH_SPEED]->(y)))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about if you found the `min` and `max` for each type of car and then matched the nodes directly for the highest and the lowest speeds and connect them.

```
match (c:CARS)
with c.name as type, min(c.score) as min_speed, max(c.score) as max_speed
match (c1:CARS {name: type, score: min_speed}), (c2:CARS {name: type, score: max_speed})
create (c1)-[:HIGH_SPEED]->(c2)
return c1, c2
```

Comment: Sweet! That Worked @Dave Bennett. I thought I would have to use FOREACH, but with your solution I got the relation I wanted across the whole node with each property. Thank you sir!